# How to supress Cytoscape.js warning for custom wheel sensitivity?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Since we updated to Cytoscape.js to version 3.3.2 we get the following warning:

> You have set a custom wheel sensitivity.This will make your app zoom
>   unnaturally when using mainstream mice. You should change this value
>   from the default only if you can guarantee that all your users will
>   use the same hardware and OS configuration as your current machine.

As we intended the mouse wheel sensitivity to be that way, the warning is superfluous in our case. How can we suppress it?

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2258

Answer (score 0):

`cytoscape.warnings(false)`

The docs say this about warnings:
Note that Cytoscape.js will print warning messages to the console to help programmers avoid mistakes. If you want to disable these messages, call `cytoscape.warnings(false)` to turn warnings off completely. You can turn them back on with `cytoscape.warnings(true)`, and you can get the current state with `cytoscape.warnings()`. It is recommended that you leave warnings enabled at least for development builds of your app.